# Redirecting to named sub-domain routes in Laravel 5.1 that share the same name?

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I've set up sub-domains in Laravel 5.1 and they work fine when manually going to the URL of the route, but when I try to redirect from my controller using a named route, the basic user home route will always be loaded regardless of the sub-domain that sent the request.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.myapp.app'], function()
{   
    Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getHome']);
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'basic.myapp.app'], function()
{   
    Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BasicController@getHome']);
});
```

One work around I found was to use

```
redirect()->to(route('home', [], false));
```

which will just return the URL of the named route. Anyone know if there is a better solution for this?

Comment: Why didnt you name the different name for the routes? Maybe like **admin.home** **basic.home**. And then in each controller, just redirect to what expected route you need. E.g: `redirect()->route('basic.home')` or `redirect()->route('admin.home')` ...

Comment: @DoanTran I've thought about that but then I'd have to check which type of user they are each time I want to redirect to home. For example, I've implemented a check on the login page that redirects to the home page if the user is already logged in. It would be much easier to just use `redirect()->route('home');` rather than checking what type of user they are.